# pandas.to_sql gets slow when amount of tables increases in SQLite3 database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a python application in which I process DataFrames with a length of approx. 10-5000 rows per DataFrame. After processing, I want to store every DataFrame as a new table in my SQLite3 database file. In general, this is really fast, since each DataFrame is not bigger than 5000 rows. However, when the amount of tables in the database file increases, the performance of each pd.to_sql gets slower. I just know this phenomenon when a DataFrame is really large, but not when the size of each DataFrame stays the same and just the amount of tables in the db file increases.

This is an example code of my application:

```
db_name = "example.db"
con = sqlite3.connect(f'./db_files/{db_name}')
con.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
for data_df in data_df_list:
  #### Processing of the DataFrame ####
  .......
  ########### Save DataFrame after processing ######
  try:
     end_df.to_sql(table_name, con, if_exists='replace', index=False, method="multi")
  except Exception as e:
     print("Error during df saving: ", e)
     con.close()
     return

# Close connection after loop is finished
con.commit()
con.close()
```

As you can see, I optimized the method parameter inside the to_sql function to "multi", but I don't know if this helps with the problem of getting slower when many tables are in the database file.
Does someone experienced a similar case and has a solution for this? I would be really glad!